# Factors on which GPS finding depends upon

Tags: android, gps

We are creating the Android app which is used to find out the location.

The Program working properly.We are getting the location. we are using Samsung Galaxy ACE to run the application.

What is our requirement is that we want the location in Maximum 25sec of time and accuracy of 10m (we have not achieved that yet) we are getting 30 meters of accuracy in 25 - 40 sec.

From our Observation we came to know that: GPS finding depends upon following factors.

1)  The device which we are using. (Samsung galaxy ace very poor quality of hardware)

2)  The place we are searching the location.

3)  The time also matters (whether day time or night).

Can any one help means can it possible to get **Maximum 25sec of time and accuracy of 10m**. What other factors on which accurate GPS location depends upon.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: You may try to mix with AGPS to get data more quickly and more correctly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS - you will need network connectivity on the device though and maybe Wifi turned on if in a city with provider wifi spots.

Comment: And in can depend on factors which you cannot take into account. For example aligning of planets or solar radiation peaks :)

Comment: @MarinoŠimić But I am using the Agps also to find the location.we are getting 70-100m (depending on place and strength of signal).35-60sec

Comment: Then it must depend a lot on the conditions and the device :( I am able to get the location down to 10 meters in half a minute on my mobile in relatively open areas of Freiburg...